# Add other domain user in TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rest, tfs, dns, domaincontroller

I have a two domain named domain1.in and domain1.in. Now i installed and create a collection project in domain1.in server. I would like to add the domain2.in user in domain1 TFS. I don't know whether its possible or not. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a trust relationship setup between domains.  Specifically, domain1 needs to trust domain2.

Here's an MSDN article on setting up trust in AD: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738617(v=ws.10).aspx