# Not able to add external users to Azure DevOps server project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server

I have admin rights to our Azure DevOps server and I manage projects, user access etc..

Recently I got a request to add users from external domain to a project in a collection.
I know the process to add users from external domain to projects in Azure DevOps services, but how do I do it, incase of Azure DevOps server, I don't see options such as policies in collection settings, like we see policies option in organization settings in Azure DevOps services.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a trust relationship setup between domains.

More information please see:

- [Create an external trust](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738617(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Trusts and Forests Considerations for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms253081(v=vs.100))

Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322141/add-other-domain-user-in-tfs-server) with the similar issue you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks for the info..How about adding external domain users in Azure devops Server ?

Comment: Can you please guide me through the steps to do it in Azure devops server ?